# Selenium consuming more RAM each time an instance is quit and a new instance is launched

Tags: python, docker, selenium, lambda, headless

I'm running Selenium with Chrome in a docker container within an AWS Lambda function for headless web scraping. While the mechanism is stable, I have to use Lambda functions that have 3GB of memory because each time I quit a chrome instance and launch a new one, the Lambda function consumes approximately 100MB more RAM than the previous iteration. Eventually, if the function stays warm long enough, all available RAM is consumed and I get a `chrome not reachable` error.

Here's an example of how I launch and exit the browser:

```py
options = Options()

# Add browser arguments
options.binary_location = '/opt/chrome/chrome'

if(headless):
        options.add_argument("--headless")
        options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
        options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
        options.add_argument("--single-process")
        options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")
        options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
        options.add_argument("--window-size=1920x1080")
        options.add_argument("--disable-dev-tools")
        options.add_argument("--no-zygote")
        options.add_argument(f"--user-data-dir={mkdtemp()}")
        options.add_argument(f"--data-path={mkdtemp()}")
        options.add_argument(f"--disk-cache-dir={mkdtemp()}")
        options.add_argument("--remote-debugging-port=9222")

# Init driver
browser = webdriver.Chrome("/opt/chromedriver" ,chrome_options=options)

self.instance = browser
```

*Note: the calls to `mkdtemp()` have been swapped out, so artifacts left in storage after a chrome session are now cleaned up correctly*

This is how I quit the browser

```py
for tab in self.instance.window_handles:
        self.instance.switch_to.window(tab)
        self.instance.close()

self.instance.stop_client()
self.instance.quit()

self.instance = None
```

Another thing I noticed is that if I log the chrome instance after calling `.quit()` I can see it still has a `session id` attached to it.

My theory is that selenium isn't able to fully kill the browser process and is leaving artifacts behind in memory. I'd like to know how to perform a cleanup after execution of my script.

Comment: It is not visible from the code, do you have all get requests before closing the browser?

Comment: @СергейКох Yes, all of my get requests are performed after launching the browser and  before closing the browser and calling `exit()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
browser = webdriver.Chrome("/opt/chromedriver" ,chrome_options=options)
self.instance = browser

try:
    # Your code

except Exception as e:
    # Log or print error

finally:
    self.instance.close()
    self.instance.quit()
```

Comment: The issue isn't any errors throwing it off, my browser close methods are called within finally blocks just as you've mentioned. The issue is reproducible even with a simple browser open, navigate to page and close cycle.

Comment: Please share your app.py (lambda_handler function). is your code pre-loaded for Lambda to use for warm start ?

Comment: Please refer to : https://stackoverflow.com/a/65789930/12906920 . AWS Lambda keeps instances of your application code running for some time to ensure subsequent requests to it are speedy, so it could simply be a matter of the garbage collection hasn't been run on that process running your code.